# How can I enable / disable form fields from within the form tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to enable / disable inputs inside a form using a checkbox. For some reason, when I place the checkbox INSIDE the form tag my javascript function won't work.
This works:

```
<input type = 'checkbox' id ='check' onchange = 'check()' checked />
<form id = 'form'>
<input type 'text' id = 'text' disabled />
</form>

<script>
function check() {
var c = document.getElementById("check");
if (c.checked == true){
    document.getElementById("text").disabled = true;
} else {
    document.getElementById("text").disabled = false;
}
}
</script>
```

However, when I try to move the input id = 'check' INSIDE the form tag, the function won't work:

```
<form id = 'form'>
<input type = 'checkbox' id ='check' onchange = 'check()' checked />
<input type 'text' id = 'text' disabled />
</form>

<script>
function check() {
var c = document.getElementById("check");
if (c.checked == true){
    document.getElementById("text").disabled = true;
} else {
    document.getElementById("text").disabled = false;
}
}
</script>
```

This must be something very silly, but I can't figure it out.
Please notice: I am trying to use this inside a bigger, multi-page form that asks from residence information first and then, in the second tab/page, asks for mailing info. So, if the checkbox is checked I want mailing info fields to be disabled.
Any idea? Help is appreciated!

Comment: do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: `<input type 'text' id = 'text' disabled />` should be `<input type='text' id = 'text' disabled />` :)

Comment: i didn't figure any issue with your first code, if you remove checked from your checkbox it will work fine if I'm not wrong have a look on this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/designerPrasanna/ct0rn3qy/

Comment: Also PLEASE: `function check() {
document.getElementById("text").disabled = document.getElementById("check").checked
}`

Comment: @Nicola Ibba Please consider marking the answer which was seriously facing you problem and explaining you the reason and not for given suggestions for "best practices". I'm not telling you because of any reputation. I'm telling you because there will be other people facing your problem go to google and find these answers most of them just reading the checked one. It would be good for education reasons to understand the logic. JS Best practices can be googled anyway. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your case window.check is ambiguous - it could be window.check the function or window.check the field with id="check"

Try to never reuse function, var an element names/IDs

To dix your immediate issue, just rename and pass the checkbox

```js
function checkIt(theCheck) {
  const c = theCheck.checked
  document.getElementById("text").disabled = c;
}
```

```html
<form id='form'>
  <input type='checkbox' id='check' onchange='checkIt(this)' checked />
  <input type='text' id='text' disabled />
</form>
```

I however STRONGLY recommend to use event listeners

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("check").addEventListener("change", function() {
    document.getElementById("text").disabled = this.checked;
  });
});
```

```html
<form id='form'>
  <input type='checkbox' id='check' checked />
  <input type='text' id='text' disabled />
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your recommendations. My question to you is: would you alway recommend using an event listener in the script rather than adding onclick or onchange in the input?

Comment: Yes. ALWAYS. Separate UI from logic

Comment: Your answer is not facing the given "Bug/Problem". You simply presented a recommendation without any explanation of what is really happening in the code.

Comment: @KingKabyle I updated to an explanation and an inline version

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that inside a form the `check` variable what you want to call will be the HtmlNode itself because it got the same name(id).
So in you code with `check()` you are try to call the HtmlNode which is for sure not a function.
If you rename the function to something like `test` it will work fine.
or use the `addEventListener` method to pass the function itself and this will also keep your code cleaner.

You can have a look in this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/k7xjv0Ls/

So this thing is probably a possibility to make it easy to manage forms it self. e.g. You don't need any `<script>` here at all, if you do something like this:

```
<form id = 'form'>
<input type = 'checkbox' id ='check' onchange = 'text.disabled = check.checked' />
<input type='text' id = 'text'/>
</form>
```

**Explanation** for all modern browsers like "Firefox, Chrome, Safari":
the id of an HTMLNode usually goes to the window object as an attribute to reference the HTMLNode itself.
If the HTMLNode is a input field **AND** it is inside a form tag it will always shadow all kinds of variables **(Named functions, vars, consts and lets)** but **just** inside the "Event Attribute" of the HTML, **not** in the javascript files or all what is inside the `<script>` tag.

Comment: Thank you all for the contributions. Changing the name of the function did it! (Yes, I also did correct the missing = but that wasn't throwing any error anyway.

Comment: It is NOT recommended to use the window scope to find the form field.
IF you MUST use this inline, at least do `onchange = 'document.getElementById("text").disabled = this.checked'`

Comment: @mplungjan I please read the complete answer. I explained the problem and presented an example to use this kind of implementation. In general I recommend to use the addEventListener method. That snippet was not to tell anybody that this is even close to a "Best practice".